# Global Alamofire request (AppDelegate)

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

My app needs to perform multiple URL requests via Alamofire but I would like to perform these tasks independently on views or what user does in UI. This basically means "on background" so the handlers which actually performing the tasks would not be deinitialized until they are done. 
My idea would be to call these requests from shared **AppDelegate** via some kind of class methods. I have only one question now:

What would be the best way to implement this scenario?

My actual knowledge would create something like this:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

   class func someKindOfClassRequest() {
   // ...
   }
   func someKindOfRequest() {
   // ...
   }
// ...
}
```

And I would call the method this way:

```
AppDelegate.someKindOfClassRequest()
```

or with not-class func, which of course will not solve the issue:

```
let sharedDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
AppDelegate.someKindOfRequest()
```

Comment: Do you mean, you don't want to interact user with UI until your one request is in progress?

Comment: Alamofire respond in closures and closures create a separate memory block. They won't get deinitialized even if the caller is deinitialized. So I think you don't have to worry about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, Alamofire uses closure-based completions so they will not get deinitialized even if the calling object is deinitialized. For the sake of keeping your code well organized, why not just create a class that does these things instead of throwing it into your `AppDelegate`? For instance, create a class called `BankgroundRequestController`:

```
class BackgroundRequestController {

    static let sharedInstance = BackgroundRequestController()

    class func someKindOfClassRequest() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then you can call these functions like:

```
BackgroundRequestController.sharedInstance.someKindOfClassRequest()
```

Comment: This is definitely the cleanest way to do this.  Many people call this class "APIClient" or something similar, depending on how much it is used for.

Comment: @creeperspeak I like the sound of `APIClient`. Seems more concise than what I use (`NetworkController`)

Comment: @toddg `APIClient`, `NetworkController`, etc. doesn't matter what you call it all that matters is that you're encapsulating that core networking logic into it's own class making it easier to call and change in the future. 

Your solution is much better than putting the code directly in the app delegate.